# CRITICAL: Curses module not found. Glances cannot start in standalone mode

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I installed glances with pip, then I run, get an error: 
**CRITICAL: Curses module not found. Glances cannot start in standalone mode.**

OS verison: Mac OS X 10.11 Beta (15A234d),
python version: 2.7.10  (installed by brew)
Pip version: 7.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, look at: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/42411